# Remove index.php from URL - codeigniter 2.1.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter. Here is the problem.  ( xiaonei is the controller )

URL like www.example.com/xiaonei/index works fine after I did what the CI user guide say.

Before I did that,URL need to be www.example.com/index.php/xiaonei/index.So I thought I

already remove the index.php.

But after I add this $route['(.*)'] = 'xiaonei/$1' to the routes.php.

URL like www.example.com/upload did not be routed to www.example.com/xiaonei/upload as what

I what to.only www.example.com/index.php/upload would work. So now I am confused. Any ideals?

Answer (score 3):

By simple .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: You updated your question. The question title and description don't match at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Tried and Tested...

At first, make sure you set the config file like the following..

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in the httpd.conf file and after that, overwrite your .htaccess file which is located your project root folder ( codeigniterdirectory/.htaccess ) **not** in the application folder ( codeigniterdirectory/application/.htaccess ) with the following code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in your config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: in this mode you define the base url and tell that the index.page is index.php and you can omitt that, have you tried it?  @user2314641

Answer (score 0):

You have everything here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

read part: Removing the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

1) Open `httpd.conf`, uncomment the line of `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

2) create .htaccess file into root directory and put exact following lines:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

3) Open `\system\application\config\config.php` and edit `$config[index_page] = "index.php";` to `$config[index_page] = "";`